# Migrating Extensions

Tags: migration, azure-devops

I am trying to migrate an Extension that was created and currently resides in our on-premises TFS instance, across to the replacement team project in VSTS. Anyone have some suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you upload and install extensions for VSTS successful now?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to migrate extensions from TFS to VSTS as below:

#### 1. Package the extension to a .vsix file (if you already has the .vsix file for your extension, skip this step)

```
npm -g tfx-cli
cd /to/your/extension
npm install vss-web-extension-sdk
tfx extension create --manifest-globs vss-extension.json
```

#### 2. Publish the extension's .vsix file into marketplace

Sign in to the [Visual Studio Marketplace Publishing Portal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers) -> New extension -> Visual Studio Team Services -> select the `.vsix` file of the extension -> Upload.

**Note:** the user who sign in the Visual Studio Marketplace Publishing Portal should be the same as publisher which specified in `vss-extension.json` file.

#### 3. Share the extension with the VSTS account you want to access

Click the `...` button of the uploaded extension -> Share/Unshare -> add the VSTS account you want to share.

[image]

#### 4. Install the extension on VSTS account

Still in Visual Studio Marketplace Publishing Portal -> `...` button for the uploaded extension -> View Extension -> Get it free -> select the VSTS account to install.

Now the extension is installed on the VSTS account.

More details, you can [refer Package, publish, unpublish, and install VSTS extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/overview?view=vsts).